Symfony Swagger\Annotations as SWG unexpected property "consumes" error
[Creation Error] An error occurred while instantiating the annotation @Operation declared on method App\Controller\Api\DesignsController::createDesignAction(): "User Warning: Ignoring unexpected property "consumes" for @Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\Operation(), expecting "x", "path", "tags", "method", "summary", "description", "externalDocs", "operationId", "parameters", "requestBody", "responses", "callbacks", "deprecated", "security", "servers" in " in /var/www/wbl/config/routes/../../src/Controller/Api/ (which is being imported from "/var/www/wbl/config/routes/annotations.yaml"). Make sure there is a loader supporting the "annotation" type.
is "consumes" property  depreciated in new version?
use Swagger\Annotations as SWG; as use OpenApi\Annotations as OA;
current existing code
     * @Operation(
     *     tags={""},
     *     summary="",
     *     consumes={"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
     *     @SWG\Parameter(
     *         name="name",
     *         in="formData",
     *         description="The name of the design",
     *         required=true,
     *         type="string"
     *     ),

can we use only "@OA\RequestBody" tag.
